# How to sort collection that contain string that represent file name?

Tags: c#

I have some folder that contain 500 files. 
Each file name is a int => that mean that each file name is for example 1.txt or 40.txt

On my code i load all those file name into array

```
string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.txt");
```

and now i need to do a sort on the files in the way that the file name is the sorted key ( `1.txt` )

How to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory API has sorting, but if this is not handling strings right (meaning "1.txt" is followed by "10.txt" not "2.txt"), you can try this:

```
  string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.txt")
                          .OrderBy(file => 
                                int.Parse(file.Substring(0, file.Length - 4)))
                          .ToArray();
```

This assumes all the files are in correct format. If this is questionable, maybe you want something like that:

```
  string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.txt")
                          .Select(file => {
                             var fileNamber;
                             if(!int.TryParse(
                                 file.Substring(0, file.Length - 4), out fileNamber)
                                 return (int?)null;
                             return (int?)fileNamber;
                          })
                          .Where(fileNamber => fileNamber.HasValue)
                          .OrderBy(fileNamber => fileNamber.Value)
                          .Select(fileNamber => fileNamber.Value + ".txt")
                          .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = allFiles.OrderBy(f => Int32.Parse(f.Split(new char[] { '.' })[0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that there are always exactly 500 files, and they are named from `1.txt` to `500.txt`, then you can simply generate the array manually, instead of scanning the directory:

```
string[] allFiles = Enumerable
                      .Range(1, 500)
                      .Select(i => Path.Combine(folderPath, $"{i}.txt"))
                      .ToArray();
```

Otherwise, parse filename without extension to int to sort it:

```
string[] allFiles = Directory
                      .GetFiles(folderPath, "*.txt")
                      .OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Substring(0, x.Length - 4)))
                      .ToArray();
```